# sql join ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B, and try to select them by sql `INNER JOIN`, but I run into this error:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

I guess it is because there are two columns' name in these two tables are the same, that is `A.column1`, `B.column1` and `A.column2` and `B.column2` (These two columns' name in A and B are the same). Since these two tables are stored in the server, I can not rename the columns. So what can I do?

This is the code I use:

```
Select * FROM A INNER JOIN B WHERE A.column1 = B.column1.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use column names with proper alias instead of using * in your query.

Comment: I guess you are not showing the full query here. I would say that in your actual query you are using a `where` clause for a column that is ambiguously defined (exists in both A and B tables but it's not exactly shown where it comes from).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you "fix" the `select`.  For instance:

```
SELECT A.*, B.col2, B.col3
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     ON A.column1 = B.column1;
```

However, you can also use a `USING` clause.  So, if the *only* naming conflict is `column1`, then:

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     USING (column1);
```

will only return it once.

Comment: Do you really mean you can't do `select *` in Oracle if two columns (in different tables) have the same name?

Comment: NO, I still get the "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" error.

Comment: SELECT A.*, B.col2, B.col3
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     ON A.column1 = B.column1;

Answer (score 0):

One or more column names from table a and table b are same.
Avoid using * in your sql statement and use table prefixes of each tables(like A.*).

Answer (score 0):

try to use alias.. for example in your case use

```
SELECT * from A as TABLE1 INNER JOIN B AS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COLUMN = TABLE2.COLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle are you using?  That works fine in 12c:

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int);

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 (c1 int, c2 int);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values (1, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1 join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1;

        C1         C2         C1         C2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          2
```

Of course, you could hit issues if you tried to use that SQL within PL/SQL e.g.

```
PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names
```